# Share ipc object between child and parent processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an Electron application where I `fork` a child process to do some background job without disturbing the main process.

```
var onlineSyncChild = require('child_process').fork('./includes/server/onlineSync');
```

I'd like to send the `ipcMain` object to the the child process so it can listen to application messages and respond accordingly. 
Here is what I have

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const ipcMain = electron.ipcMain;
```

...

```
var onlineSyncChild = require('child_process').fork('./includes/server/onlineSync');
onlineSyncChild.on('message', function (m) {
  console.log('onlineSync says: ', m);
});
// send the ipcMain object into child
onlineSyncChild.send({type: 'set', ipc: ipcMain, db: DB});
```

However when I try to use it inside child process,

```
this.ipc.on('query-online-status', this.ipcQueryOnlineStatus);
```

I'm getting an error that `this.ipc.on` is not a function.

Am I correct to assume that this not possible, and all I can do send regular object only between child and parent processes?

Answer (score 1):

The message you pass to `onlineSyncChild.send()` will be serialized to a JSON string before being sent to the child process so any functions in the `message` will be omitted. You can read more about what's omitted during the serialization process in the documentation of [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).